# sql filter condition, add date filter

Tags: sql, date, filter

I want to adjust the below SQL statement to select a date range.
Date range = this year

```
call.afdelingoorzaakanalyse.id IN (select distinct c.afdelingoorzaakanalyse 
                                   from call c 
                                   group by c.afdelingoorzaakanalyse 
                                   having count(*) > 250)
```

call = table with alert message records

afdelingoorzaakanalyse = field with department categories

Thanks!

Structure of call table:

```
'data.frame':   22227 obs. of  208 variables:
$ cal_id                           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ cal_deleted                      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ cal_insertedby                   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_insertedon                   : POSIXct, format: "2005-09-01 08:35:00" "2005-09-01 08:43:00" "2005-09-01 08:46:00" "2005-09-02 15:21:00" ...
$ cal_updatedby                    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ cal_updatedon                    : POSIXct, format: "2007-11-20 15:47:17" "2007-11-20 15:47:17" "2007-11-20 15:47:17" "2007-11-20 15:47:17" ...
$ cal_finishedby                   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_finishedon                   : POSIXct, format: "2005-09-08 08:26:00" "2005-09-08 08:27:00" "2005-10-12 13:37:00" "2005-09-12 07:54:00" ...
$ cal_file                         : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_notes                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_workflow                     : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_status                       : int  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 ...
$ cal_supplier                     : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_order                        : int  16176 16179 16195 16191 16188 16188 16188 16188 16188 16189 ...
$ cal_type                         : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_problemarea                  : int  311 311 311 121 311 311 311 311 311 311 ...
$ cal_problemaereadetail           : int  NA NA NA 333 327 380 123 380 NA 385 ...
$ cal_problemclass                 : int  NA NA NA 125 207 125 125 207 207 202 ...
$ cal_problemsubclass              : int  NA NA NA 198 NA 197 198 250 250 218 ...
$ cal_repairer                     : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_causer                       : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_hours                        : int  NA NA NA NA 32 32 32 32 32 NA ...
$ cal_costshours                   : int  NA NA NA NA 2080 2080 2080 2080 2080 NA ...
$ cal_costsmaterial                : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_coststransport               : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_totalcostsexp                : int  NA NA NA NA 2080 2080 2080 2080 2080 NA ...
$ cal_totalcostsreal               : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_percentage                   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_cause                        : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_subcause                     : int  NA NA NA NA 161 160 160 160 160 NA ...
$ cal_deadlineherstelactie         : POSIXct, format: NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_deadlineanalyseactie         : POSIXct, format: NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_reference                    : Factor w/ 1459 levels "-","---","-----",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_afdelingoorzaakanalyse       : int  NA NA NA 76 76 76 76 76 76 NA ...
$ cal_afdelinghersteller           : int  78 78 78 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ cal_koopbriefnr                  : Factor w/ 5714 levels "'-","-","--",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: A table named call... Do yourself a favor, try to avoid SQL keywords as table names.

Comment: jarlh, thank you for your advice... I'm not in charge of the naming convention of the data base, I can only read it.

Comment: read the question 3 times, still not sure what you want us to help with.

Comment: Give us the structure of table  `call`

Comment: I don't understand that structure. What is `Factor w/ 5714 levels` supposed to mean as a column's data type? Or `POSIXct, format: NA NA NA NA ...` Please [edit] your question and add the `create table`  statement

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: We use SQL server 2005

Answer (score 0):

What I've used to make it work is the following:

```
call.insertedby.afdeling IN (283,282,281,280,279,101,76,75)
                         AND call.deleted=FALSE
                         AND YEAR(call.insertedon) = YEAR(getdate())
```

Though not the original code presented above, the "AND YEAR" part provides me the data set of the running year